# App crash in webview

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have webviews in my Application and I am getting a strange crash most frequently. I think its due to the webview , kindly tell me is there any solution for it or any suggestions .I have attached the screen shot to elaborate it
Thanks[image]

Comment: Most likely your issue is due to the fact that you are doing something with a web view on a background thread. You must be sure to work wit the web view only on the main thread.

Comment: but I am not doing anything with webview in background thread

Comment: The stack trace makes it look like you are.

Comment: But I am unable to find point of failure, can you please guide me that how I can trace the exact point of failure .because this crash is not too frequent and Organizer don't take me to the line of crash.

Comment: @rmaddy waiting for comment from your side